# Is there an equivalent column to Votes.UserId in the Data Explorer, or was this missed?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

Maybe I'm going crazy, but I can't find a `UserId` column in the `Votes` table in the [Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/), even though it's listed as part of the schema [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump). Was this missed, omitted on purpose, or ...?

Comment: As jeff commented, `we did put this file in the data dump, FYI -- so please add more if you want to see additional stuff next time. `

Comment: @Kop: Huh? I know the data exists in the data dump already, I'm just wondering why it's not in the Data Explorer.

Comment: ill get this sorted (keep in mind its only there for vote type 5)

Comment: @waffles Any chance of a UserHash column (say) that anonymises users, but allows us to get statistics on voting patterns? (Of course you couldn't have this field _and_ a valid UserId for vote type 5, or the anonymous hash suddenly isn't anonymous any more.)

Comment: @Mark Im a bit afraid that would end up de-anonymizing stuff, meaning if somebody had 312 upvotes and 96 downvotes (via the User table) you could possibly correlate with the hash.

Comment: @waffles Yeah, fair enough. I can't think of a way of providing useful data with complete anonymity ensured.

Comment: @waffles sorry, could you clarify "only there fore vote type 5"? ANSWER - It's only available for favourite votes...i.e. VOTETYPE 5.

Comment: @slotishtype Now it's also available for BountyStart votes (with VoteTypeId = 8): [Add UserId information for bounty starters and closers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110182/158912)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

completed upvote so its not kicked anymore