# How many people reach the up/down voting limit per day?

Tags: statistics, voting, discussion, voting-limits

In [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28314/why-are-there-voting-limits), a number of people have commented that they do not regularly hit the maximum of 30 up or down votes per day. This leads me to wondering: how many people *do* hit the limit per day on average?

It would be nice to have a graph of this average over time for at least Stack Overflow. I suspect that the average is different from the average when the "Why are there voting limits?" question was first asked in 2008.

Comment: I don't think there's enough info in, say, Stexdex, since at that point votes have already been anonymized. You can do simple daily average calcs and stuff, though.

Comment: I hit often!...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the only way this data could be obtained is through querying the live database (i.e., it's not possible for us regular users).

The voting information is anonymized in any public-facing data export (including the data dump and in turn Data Explorer), meaning that you can't see which votes are attributed to which user. (Favorite votes *are* attributed to users publicly, but will be in Data Explorer only when [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53432/is-there-an-equivalent-column-to-votes-userid-in-the-data-explorer-or-was-this-m) gets completed.)

That being said, I think it would be an interesting stat to find out. Most likely, the current voting limit is already tuned based on this information.

Answer (score 1):

I only hit the vote limit on SO once, when I went into one of the retro community wiki poll questions with hundreds of posts and up- or down-voted lots of entries.  The introduction of the Electorate badge resulted in me never doing that sort of thing again.

On meta, I often hit the vote limit through *comments*, if there is some sort of controversy that day that elicits dozens of comments*. However I never reach it on questions/answers, unless again there is something really eventful happening that day.

*<sub>like for instance, someone getting banned, or a new feature is suddenly launched without any community discussion. You know, *those* questions.</sub>